# SubstituteBindings Middleware doesn't make the difference between slug and custom route name

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

I have all those routes:

```
Route::resource('tournaments', 'TournamentController');
Route::get('/tournaments/deleted', 'TournamentController@getDeleted');
```

When I access

```
/tournaments/deleted
```

I get a

```
Model Not Found
```

in

```
SubstituteBindings Middleware
```

that think deleted is my tournament slug.

How should I solve this???

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to define first the getDeleted Route, and then define ressource :

Working :

```
Route::get('/tournaments/deleted', 'TournamentController@getDeleted')->name('getDeleted'); // Already has auth middleware
Route::resource('tournaments', 'TournamentController');
```

Not Working :

```
Route::resource('tournaments', 'TournamentController');
Route::get('/tournaments/deleted', 'TournamentController@getDeleted')->name('getDeleted'); // Already has auth middleware
```